# WCF consume web service and network architecture

Tags: wcf, networking, websocket, nat, portforwarding

I'm getting start WCF soap web service. Trying to implement a flexible, hot-plug featured, interoperable web service.

A device consumes server service (predefined IP address) which means registering to server, and then service asks device returning all configuration information of a device. Service remotely control those registered devices later.

**Network Architecture**

Please see the diagram below. A Server-side service is listening on 80 port. We had a router (Router B) which connects to the Server, and set NAT table 220.120.20.209:80 mapping to 192.168.0.3:80. 220.120.20.209 is a public IP.

Two Clients connect to a router (Router A) and have private IP addresses relatively(170.15.40.1/ 170.15.40.2) . Clients host a service (called DeviceService) listening on 80 port. And we didn't set NAT on Router A. 68.250.250.1 is a public IP.

**Operation**

1. (Request a Registration) Client sends (request) a message to a Service.
2. (Response) Service response a message.
3. (Get Config from Devices) Service consumes client through calling like  http:  //clientsIP:80/DeviceService.

Operation 1, 2 is working to me. To my understanding, incoming ip address of client#1 is 68.250.250.1 (I'm using **RemoteEndpointMessageProperty** to get the caller's address).

My question is "operation 3 is not working". Server can't access Client's private IP because of a Router/firewall.Only did Server get is 68.250.250.1. How can I solve this kind of problem? the problem have to do with Network Architecture?

I googled all day long found nothing to do with my problem. But I found websocket thing. Websocket is capable of full-duplex communication over Tcp. Does that mean once a client built a connection with a Server, Server can do operation 3 (Get Config from Devices) anytime even under my network architecture?

[image]

**Updated 2014/4/24**

Thanks a lot to @vtortola. After studying those references , I am still confused that if it's possible to allow call a self-host service from client during a callback session?

Try to elaborate what I thought

1. Clients will have a self-host service at first. e.g. Providing Configuration Service
2. Let the Client drive the interaction first, and built a bi-direction channel between Client and Server.
3. Client requests, and Server response. At the same time, Server triggers the callback procedure.
4. Server requests "Providing Configuration" message to client via channel during the period callback is fired.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work that way if Router A is doing NAT. RouterA has only an TCP 80 port. Even if you forward it to Client#1, then Client#2 won't work. And I assume RouterA is doing NAT because the client IP addresses are private, so it is translating them to a public IP address.

I think you are messing two concepts. NAT (Network Address Translation) is about IP addresses, it has nothing to do with ports. With NAT you allow your client private IP addresses be translated to the public IP address and therefore get into the internet. Port Forwarding is a technique that allows to map a TCP or UDP port in the public interface of the router to a particular local IP address. Router B is doing NAT to allow the Server communicate with internet through the public interface, and port forwarding to allow hosts in internet to access Server's TCP 80 port, by accessing its TCP 80 port.

Let the Client drive the interaction. In operation #3, the client should send the device configuration after getting the server response in #2.

If you need the server to lead some of the interactions, you must then use a [duplex WCF service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). WebSocket is one of the duplex WCF bindings. But again, the channel must be established from client to server first.

- [A Beginner's Guide to Duplex WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF)
- [Duplex Service in WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/660479/Duplex-Service-in-WCF)
- [WCF and WebSockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674271%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)